# Symfony Entities console error generate

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, entities

Hi there i would like to create entities by console but give me an error i can't solve.

I've reading a lot about this error but i can't fix it.

1.-

```
php bin/console generate:bundle
```

2.-

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert xml ./src/BlogBundle/Resources/config/doctrine/metadata/orm --from-database --force
```

3.-

```
php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import BlogBundle yml
```

4.-

```
php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities BlogBundle
```

And the error is on 4th step:

```
C:\x\x\x\x\projecte>php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities BlogBundle:User


  [Doctrine\ORM\ORMException]
  Unknown Entity namespace alias 'BlogBundle'.


doctrine:generate:entities [--path PATH] [--no-backup] [-h|--help] [-q|--quiet] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-V|--version] [--ansi] [--no-ansi] [-n|--no-interaction] [-e|--env ENV] [--no-debug] [--] <command> <name>
```

PD: i'm using symfony 3.3

Answer (score 1):

I use this commands to **generate entities**:

1. `php bin/console doctrine:mapping:import --force AppBundle --env=local --em=myentityManager`
2. `php bin/console doctrine:mapping:convert annotation ./src --env=local --em=entityManager`
3. Delete orm.xml Files generated
4. `php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AppBundle:User --env=local`

Answer (score 0):

By Symfony conventions, the BlogBundle namespace goes under your company or project name (e.g. Acme\BlogBundle). So your BlogBundle should be prefixed with the company name like this:

```
C:\x\x\x\x\projecte>php bin/console doctrine:generate:entities AcmeBlogBundle:User
```

Just replace **Acme** with whatever subfolder your BlogBundle lives under and it should work.